# React TypeScript: Correct type for useLocation() from react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-router-dom

I'm struggling to find the right type for this situation. This is a simplified version of redirecting after login. The following produces a compiler error:

```
Property 'from' does not exist on type '{} | { from: { pathname: string; }; }'.
```

Adding `as any` to the use of `location.state` fixes the compiler error but it's ugly and the linter complains.

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const AuthLayer: React.FC = (props) => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };

  return <p></p>;
};

export default AuthLayer;
```

Answer (score 34):

You can create a particular type or interface to describe your location state and then use it when calling a `useLocation` hook:

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

interface LocationState {
  from: {
    pathname: string;
  };
}

const AuthLayer: React.FC = (props) => {
  const location = useLocation<LocationState>();

  const { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };

  return <p></p>;
};

export default AuthLayer;
```

Comment: Thank you for this response.  A state variable was breaking on me after some changes were made in TypeScript showing that my state variable was 'unknown.'  The solution you provided worked perfectly.

Comment: This does not work even with @types/react-router-dom. What am I missing? `"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"` & `"@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3"`. Says `Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.`

Comment: @duduwe it's a bit different in version 6, const locationState = useLocation().state as {id: string}; 

const id = locationState.id;

Comment: @SalwaA.Soliman yeah, just went with assertion

Answer (score 26):

Type Assertion would work here.

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

type LocationState = {
  from: {
    path: string;
  }
}

const AuthLayer: React.FC = (props) => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const { from } = location.state as LocationState;

  return <p></p>;
};

export default AuthLayer;
```

Also, remember to define the type, as per your requirements.
For example, you might be using `navigate(state.from)`.

For this Define the type as -

```
type LocationState = {
  from : string;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use Location from 'history'.

```
import React from "react";
import { Location } from "history";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";


const AuthLayer: React.FC = (props) => {
  const location = useLocation<Location>();

  const { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };

  return <p></p>;
};

export default AuthLayer;
```

Comment: After doing a console.log of location that's the right answer for me, the object returned was corresponding

Comment: Mine says `Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.`

Answer (score 3):

This will be a little type-safe since it will return `undefined` if `from` is not in the object instead of throwing an error.

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

type LocationState = {
  from: {
    path: string;
  }
}

const AuthLayer: React.FC = (props) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  
  // 
  const from = (location.state as LocationState)?.from;

  return <p></p>;
};

export default AuthLayer;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
export interface LocationParams {
  pathname: string;
  state: your_state_data_type;
  search: string;
  hash: string;
  key: string;
}

//...
const location = useLocation<LocationParams>()
```

or create a generic that u can use any where

```
// types.ts
export interface LocationParams<Data> {
  pathname: string;
  state: Data;
  search: string;
  hash: string;
  key: string;
}


// App.tsx
import { LocationParams } from './types.ts'

// ...
const location = useLocation<LocationParams<your_data_here>>()
```

Answer (score 1):

In react-router-dom version 6, it can be done like that

```
const locationState = useLocation().state as {id: string}; 

const id = locationState.id;
```

Comment: only answer that looks nice. for me useLocation is not generic so other solutions not working

Answer (score -4):

If you send only one thing, What about using useParams instead of useLocation?

```
function routeDetails(id: string) {
    history.push({
      pathname: `/details/${pathname}`,
    });
  }
```

```
const { id } = useParams<{ id: string }>();
```

You can use useParams simply.
It has key 'id' that is from history pathname.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31843865)