# Getting "Object is of type 'unknown'." error on location.state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, typescript-typings

I'm using the `useLocation` hook like this -> `const location = useLocation();`. Then I try to pass it to the prop of a React element like this:

```
 <DatePicker
     endDate={location.state?.fields?.some(
         (f: string) => f === 'endDate'
     )}
     {...field}
 />
```

But I get the `location.state` underscored and the following error -> `Object is of type 'unknown'.`

Comment: Have you installed types for react router dom library??

Comment: @Soheb Yeah -> "@types/react-router-dom": "5.3.3" but my react-router-dom's version is - "react-router-dom": "6.2.2". Could that be the problem?

Comment: That's the latest types available for react-router-dom..., can you try to define the type to check if that solves the problem

Comment: @Soheb But what type am I supposed to be using?

Comment: I think we should import Location from history and pass it as const location = useLocation<Location>(), try this

Comment: Did you try this??

Comment: @Soheb Yeah, I just did but I get an error that says useLocation expected 0 type arguements but received 1.

Comment: Are you passing as an argument it should be outside of parentheses

Comment: @Soheb I'm not passing it as argument, I copied it too

Comment: Can you try using like useLocation: Location = useLocation()

Comment: "Could that be the problem?" yes, that is most likely the culprit. You should use the same major version for the package and the typings.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion to handle this issue you can try these two ways:
On the first try, refer to the following question link and test its answer:
[React TypeScript: Correct type for useLocation() from react-router-dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61668623/react-typescript-correct-type-for-uselocation-from-react-router-dom) .
If it didn't work for you properly, try following way using [`lodash` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash):

```js
import get from 'lodash/get'
 
 ...
 
 <DatePicker
 get(location, 'state.procedureDetail.description', '')
     emphasize={get(location, 'state.some') &&
       get(location, 'state.some')(
           (f: string) => f === 'endDate'
       )
     }
     data-testid="collection-form-end-date"
     type="datetime-local"
     {...field}
 />
```