# How expand typescript type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-typescript

I have a location that returns a Location that has an undefined state (unknown). I can't figure out how I can extend the Location interface type so that I don't get an error that `from` doesn't exist.

TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.

```
  const location: Location = useLocation();

  const fromPage: string = location.state?.from || ENDPOINTS.GET_LIST_REPORTS;
```

Comment: Location it is -  export interface Location extends Path {
   state: unknown;
    key: Key;

Answer (score 0):

You can use the generic type of `useLocation()`.

```
interface LocationState {
  from: {
    pathname: string;
  };
}
const location = useLocation<LocationState>();

const { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };
```

Code from answer in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61669105/4490246

Comment: it`s not held . When i add <LocationState> i get the following error - TS2558: Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your `Location` with type

```
type ExtendedLocation = Location & { from: string }

const location = useLocation<ExtendedLocation>();

const fromPage: string = location.state?.from || ENDPOINTS.GET_LIST_REPORTS;
```

Or with an extended interface

```
interface ExtendedLocation extends Location {
  from: string
}

const location = useLocation<ExtendedLocation>();

const fromPage: string = location.state?.from || ENDPOINTS.GET_LIST_REPORTS;
```

Comment: if i take type i get error TS2322: Type 'Location' is not assignable to type 'ExtendedLocation'.   Type 'Location' is not assignable to type '{ state?: { form: string; } | undefined; }'.     Types of property 'state' are incompatible.       Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '{ form: string; } | undefined'.

Comment: with interface i get 2 error )

Comment: with interface first error - TS2430: Interface 'ExtendedLocation' incorrectly extends interface 'Location'.   Property 'state' is optional in type 'ExtendedLocation' but required in type 'Location'.. and when i change this error i get next  TS2322: Type 'Location' is not assignable to type 'ExtendedLocation'.   Types of property 'state' are incompatible.     Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '{ form: string; }'

Comment: @Timofeus91 I modified my answer for the sake of your requirement. You can verify it and let me know your feedback on that

Comment: const location = useLocation<ExtendedLocation>(); - this not work. Error at useLocation<ExtendedLocation>() - TS2558: Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1. Thanks for you help!)

Comment: hmm that's weird, could you tell me which `react-router-dom` version are you using? Or where does your `useLocation` come from? @Timofeus91

Comment: yes, my version 6.2.2